# Run CLion Full Remote Mode C++ program as root

Tags: c++, remote-debugging, clion, bluez, superuser

I am developing some code using the BlueZ Bluetooth stack and running it requires root privileges. As example running `hcitool lescan` as normal user returns `Set scan parameters failed: Operation not permitted`, which is also seen from my C++ code where `hci_le_set_scan_parameters()` functions returns `-1`.

The question [Run a C++ program in Clion as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927781/run-a-c-program-in-clion-as-root) is about running C++ program as root in CLion on the local machine, which can be as simple as running the CLion as root.

I have configured [Full Remote Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html) with remote toolchain:
[image]

and then I'm using this same configuration for automatic deployment:
[image]

and then the *Run/Debug Configurations* are automatically run as this user on the remote machine.

I could replace `Non-superuser user` in Deployment configuration with `root` and probably solve the problem (by also giving root privileges to whole *Remote Host Browser*) - but is there any other way to achieve this any only run the built executable with `sudo`?

Comment: Could you meanwhile find a solution?

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately I did not, I went with "print debugging" and run executable manually. Interestingly, a while ago I noticed PyCharm option "_Execute code using this interpreter with root privileges via sudo_" when configuring remote Python interpreters.

Comment: Thansk for your reply! I ended up writing a small shell script that is launched after the build task (can be configured in CLion's run configuration) and that changes the owner to root and also sets the setuid bit of the executable such that the program is executed as root. Also, I have added this executable into sudoers with the NOPASSWD flag so that I don't need to enter the password every time. Quite hacky but it works ;-)